# How to make cross origin calls with Phonegap (Django server in Heroku)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cors

I'm starting to develop with phonegap, but when making `GET` request via Ajax to my Django server in Heroku, I don't get response because of CORS protection.

How could I do this?

I'm noob with Phonegap, so an example will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding headers be it on middleware level or server.I will recommend django middle ware route take a look at django-cors [git link](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) worked fine for me.Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. In the meanwhile... any tip?

Comment: its easy and you shouldn't face any problems as long as you are trying to do get requests, if you want to do post then you may have to use post messages in that case take a look at porthole.js [http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/]